# Spring WebFlux WebClient: delay execution

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

When I define and call a client method like this:

```
webClient.get()
            .uri(endpoint)
            .headers(this::configureHttpHeaders)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
```

the `retrieve` method gets executed even if I do nothing with the returned Mono.

I would have expected that it only gets called when someone (a subscriber ?) actually want to get data from the Mono.

Why does it get called immediately? How can I change this behaviour?

For more context: in my case I only want it to be executed when CacheFlux onCacheMissResume gets triggered:

```
    Flux<T> defaulValue= client.getStringMono()
            .flatMapIterable(mapper::readObjects);

    CacheFlux.<String, T>lookup(key -> readFluxFromCache(cacheName, key), cacheKey)
                .onCacheMissResume(defaulValue)
                .andWriteWith((key, valueSignal) -> writeFluxToCache(cacheName, key, valueSignal))
```

Comment: That method is probably called because it's part of the assembly of the Mono, but it's not actual execution, I believe: https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription

You can verify the behavior by adding a doOnNext operator after the WebClient call and putting a break point inside it. It should not be called if you have a cache hit.

Comment: I think it has to do with what is called `hot` and `cold` publishers. You can read more about them here https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold To transform a hot publisher to a cold publisher you can use the `defer` function.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf defer is what we're currently using now. If you add an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with what is called hot and cold publishers.

You can read more about them here [projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold) To transform a hot publisher to a cold publisher you can use the `defer` function.